# Hashes and Ciphers

Tags: encryption, hash

So I'm brand new to cryptography, I'm confused on a few fundamental issues, and my normal avenues of research aren't bearing any fruit.  I'm hoping someone can describe the relationship between cryptographic hash algorithms like MD5 or SHA and encryption protocols such as RSA, IPSec, or 3DES.

Comment: RSA is an (public key, so assymetric) algorithm, 3DES is a symmetric algorithm. Both are not protocols, but building blocks in cipher-modes, which in turn are used in protocols, like IPSec, TLS, SSH, etc. The last use hashes as part of HMAC's (mostly) to ensure that data is not tempered with, and in key-derivation.

Comment: Have you lookd up the definitions (e.g. on Wikipedia)? What part don't you understand? It isn't really possible to meaningfully answer “what's the difference between a fish and a bicycle or a railway or a truck”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental difference between hash and encryption techniques is that hash is irreversible while encryption is reversible.

Hash algorithms generate a digest of fixed length output cipher text for a given input plain text. The output text cannot be converted back to input text. The generated output will always be same for a given input plain text that is hashed using any one of the hashing algorithms(`MD5`, `SHA` etc), no matter how many times the process is repeated.

Encryption technique employs secret keys to encrypt plain text and convert it into cipher text but different from hashing mechanism since this process is reversible i.e, the cipher text can be decrypted back to plain text using the secret key. However, there are variations in encryption algorithms in the way the keys are used.

1) Symmetric encryption algorithms(like `AES`, `DES`, `RC2` etc') use the same key for encryption and decryption purposes.

2) Asymmetric algorithms(like `RSA`, `DSA` etc') use public and private key pairs to encrypt & decrypt plain text.

Comment: OP here. So they have no relationship, they have separate functions. Hashes are used for data verification, like password checks and encryption is used for secure transmission. Is that right?

Comment: @Brandon I wouldn't say hashfunctions and (symmetric) ciphers are completely unrelated. For example, it's possible to build a hash function from a block cipher. But they (often) have different use-cases, if that's what you mean.